# Generate all possible substrings in sequence

Tags: python, substring, permutation, n-gram

I'm searching for a library or an efficient way to implement the following in Python

```
Input: 
"He was hungry"

Desired Output:
[["He","was","hungry"]
["He was","hungry"]
["He","was hungry"]
["He was hungry"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def f(a):
    if(len(a) == 0):
        yield []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for c in f(a[i+1:]):
            yield [" ".join(a[:i+1]), *c]


s = "He was hungry"
print(list(f(s.split())))

[['He', 'was', 'hungry'], ['He', 'was hungry'], ['He was', 'hungry'], ['He was hungry']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive approach: For an input with N words, calculate the possible joinings of the first N-1 words, then choose whether to append the final word as its own element or join it with the rightmost element.

```
def iter_joinings(items):
    if len(items) == 0:
        return
    elif len(items) == 1:
        yield items
    else:
        right = items[-1]
        for left_a in iter_joinings(items[:-1]):
            left_b = left_a.copy()
            left_a.append(right)
            yield left_a
            left_b[-1] = left_b[-1] + " " + right
            yield left_b

s = "He was hungry"
for result in iter_joinings(s.split()):
    print(result)
```

Result:

```
['He', 'was', 'hungry']
['He', 'was hungry']
['He was', 'hungry']
['He was hungry']
```

---

And here's an iterative version, just in case you have inputs with 999 elements and don't want to hit Python's maximum recursion depth:

```
import itertools

def iter_joinings(items):
    for decisions in itertools.product((False, True), repeat=len(items)-1):
        result = [items[0]]
        for idx, should_append in enumerate(decisions, 1):
            if should_append:
                result.append(items[idx])
            else:
                result[-1] = result[-1] + " " + items[idx]
        yield result

s = "He was hungry"
for result in iter_joinings(s.split()):
    print(result)
```

... Although such a huge input would take around 10^300 bytecode instructions to execute in either case, so this is unlikely to be a practical issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned n-gram, this might be what you are after:

```
s = "He was hungry"
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
c = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, len(s))).fit([s])
c.vocabulary_

{'he': 0,
 'was': 4,
 'hungry': 3,
 'he was': 1,
 'was hungry': 5,
 'he was hungry': 2}
```